# How do I connect a late 2013 MBP Retina to two DVI monitors?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, displayport

I thought this [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter](http://www.apple.com/s/AI9j1f3) would allow me to connect two of [these monitors](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/products/monitors/topics/en/monitor_3007wfp?c=us) to my Retina MBP.  Does "Dual-Link" mean that two monitors could be connected?  It had not occurred to me to question that before I bought the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The Dual Link DVI adaptor is for connecting screens ~30" – not for connect multiple screens.

You would need to connect one via the Thunderbolt port and one via the HDMI port.